# how to successfully run docker image as container

Tags: python, docker

Below my docker file,

```
FROM python:3.9.0
ARG WORK_DIR=/opt/quarter_1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install cron -y && apt-get install -y default-jre
# Install python libraries
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
WORKDIR $WORK_DIR
EXPOSE 8888
VOLUME /home/data/quarter_1/
# Copy etl code
# copy code on container under your workdir "/opt/quarter_1"
COPY . .
```

I tried to connect to the server then i did the build with `docker build -t my-python-app .`
when i tried to run the container from a build image i got nothing and was not able to do it.

```
  docker run -p 8888:8888 -v /home/data/quarter_1/:/opt/quarter_1 image_id
```

[image] work here is opt

Answer (score 0):

**Update based on comments**

If I understand everything you've posted correctly, my suggestion here is to use a base Docker Jupyter image, modify it to add your pip requirements, and then add your files to the work path. I've tested the following:

Start with a dockerfile like below

```
FROM jupyter/base-notebook:python-3.9.6

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

COPY ./quarter_1 /home/jovyan/quarter_1
```

Above assumes you are running the build from the folder containing dockerfile, "requirements.txt", and the "quarter_1" folder with your build files.

Note "home/joyvan" is the default working folder in this image.

Build the image

```
docker build -t biwia-jupyter:3.9.6 .
```

Start the container with open port to 8888. e.g.

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 biwia-jupyter:3.9.6
```

Connect to the container to access token. A few ways to do but for example:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME bash
jupyter notebook list
```

Copy the token in the URL and connect using your server IP and port. You should be able to paste the token there, and afterwards access the folder you copied into the build, as I did below.

[Jupyter screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TjJJ.png)

If you are deploying the image to different hosts this is probably the best way to do it using COPY/ADD etc., but otherwise look at using Docker Volumes which give you access to a folder (for example quarter_1) from the host, so you don't constantly have to rebuild during development.

**Second edit for Python 3.9.0 request**

Using the method above, 3.9.0 is not immediately available from DockerHub. I doubt you'll have much compatibility issues between 3.9.0 and 3.9.6, but we'll build it anyway. We can download the dockerfile folder from github, update a build argument, create our own variant with 3.9.0, and do as above.

Assuming you have git. Otherwise download the repo manually.

1. Download the Jupyter Docker stack repo

   `git clone https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks`
2. change into the base-notebook directory of the cloned repo

   `cd ./base-notebook`
3. Build the image with python 3.9.0 instead

   `docker build --build-arg PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.0 -t jupyter-base-notebook:3.9.0 .`
4. Create the version with your copied folders and 3.9.0 version from the steps above, replacing the first line in the dockerfile instead with:

   `FROM jupyter-base-notebook:3.9.0`

I've tested this and it works, running Python 3.9.0 without issue.

There are lots of ways to build Jupyter images, this is just one method. Check out [docker hub for Jupyter](https://hub.docker.com/u/jupyter)  to see their variants.

Comment: thank you, i will try, should i replace $JUPYTER_NOTEBOOK_DIR with my $WORK_DIR
? let's say that i don"t want to run it from localhost but from my server(ip:172.17.10.177) where i created the image .

Comment: That was just the environmental variable I set for my folder directory. If my Jupyter files were in `/opt/quarter_1`, I would set my JUPYTER_NOTEBOOK_DIR with `ENV JUPYTER_NOTEBOOK_DIR /opt/quarter_1` followed by the entrypoint and command I listed above.

For the localhost vs. server, it just depends what you are running your docker container on. If it's Docker Desktop, localhost:8888, otherwise if it's on a server (for example Docker Context or whatever), just ensure the port is accessible (8888) and then it's SERVERIP:8888.

Comment: when i did ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
CMD ["jupyter-notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --notebook-dir $JUPYTER_NOTEBOOK_DIR"] and then docker ps i have no container running

Comment: I see you have changed the post title to remove Jupyter Notebooks, are you trying to run Jupyter Notebooks or a custom Python application (presumably stored within "/home/data/quarter_1/")?

Comment: An app which is a group of jupyter notebooks .

Comment: Okay, well my advice above is related to just a single standard Notebook server, so your app sounds potentially a bit more than that.

If you've got a python app which you would usually start with `python main.py` inside a working folder on your local machine, when you transfer that working folder to Docker (with your VOLUME) command, your starting command should be `python $PATH_TO_MAIN/main.py` (where you could set $PATH_TO_MAIN with `ENV PATH_TO_MAIN /opt/quarter_1`, and it should run as normal on that container, and accessible through the port.

Comment: sorry its me i was not that clear . I want to run new jupyter notebook in my quarter_1 project. Please have a look at my photo added in my original post . Please excuse me

Comment: do you see what i mean ?

Comment: Please see my updated original post. Hopefully that will get you going if I've understood everything you've said correctly.

Comment: thank you will test. but it is little bit different your image .. can you test with my python image **python:3.9.0** please so that we can have exactly same results.

Comment: thank you! why do you build jupyter image too, as i have jupyter package in my requirements.txt it will be ok no?

Comment: I occasionally do that just for reliability purposes, i.e. extend tried and tested images without worrying about user permissions, entrypoints and commands rather than fully building from scratch. But yes I have done it from scratch with a Python docker image, pip install jupyter, copy the files over and set up the entrypoint and start up command as we discussed. As I say just lots of different ways to do it.